How parameters of structured products on real options are set in practice?
I know that it is a really general question and that probably the answers will differ based on the type of products. But I would like to remain at a very high level of reasoning.

Suppose I have a company that every year gets some revenues (we may
suppose that they are normally distributed). Now, suppose further that
I want to create a product that gives the right to operate my company
to a counterparty, where the buyer must give me a floor on the
revenues and everything above is shared by some %. (Thus the payoff
from my side is a constant_floor + call_option * profit_sharing).

How the floor is fixed? I was thinking by using VaR or percentile on the distribution of the revenues, but this would work only if I have historical data which allow me to estimate it. Moreover, should I use real world or risk neutral measure in these cases?
There are some articles/books that discuss these type of problems?
